# Why is all content on my home page overflowing the body border?

Tags: html, css, document-body

On my home page Kendall_Gregory.html, my body border is ignoring the contents in the body and setting an arbitrary border around the page. It ignores every image that is on the page and the divs around them. The same code works on other pages and i can't figure out why this is the exception.

[image: Body border not around all of contents]

https://jsfiddle.net/hgaLsaz6/3/

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <a href="Html/MenuPage.html">
        <img id="topMenu" src="http://s4.postimg.org/7636jv04p/menu_Top.png">
    </a>
</div>

<img id="headerImage" src="http://s16.postimg.org/uqbzk51yd/Header.png">

<div class ="card">
    <div class="no-hover"> 
        <!-- <span class = "caption"> Fade </span> -->
        <img class="left Fade" src="http://s16.postimg.org/monr28j6t/Fade_Mag.png">
        <!-- hover image -->
    </div>
    <div class="on-hover">
        <a href="Html/Fade.html">
            <img class="left Fade" src="http://s21.postimg.org/o0f1chw13/Xenia_Lally_Hover.png">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- GE -->

<div class ="card">
    <div class="no-hover"> 

        <!-- <span class = "caption"> GE </span> -->
        <img class="whiteOverlay right GE" src="http://s16.postimg.org/6vislrw9x/image.png">
    </div>
    <div class="on-hover">
        <a href="Html/GE.html">
            <img class="whiteOverlay right GE" src="http://s21.postimg.org/6yhlwnrs7/GE_hover.png">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Kaleidoscope -->
<div class ="card">
    <div class="no-hover"> 
        <img class="left KALEIDOSCOPE " src="http://s16.postimg.org/5fcc0qzol/KALEIDOSCOPE_Thumb.png">

    </div>
    <div class="on-hover mt100">
        <a href="Html/Pantene.html">
            <img class="left KALEIDOSCOPE" src="http://s16.postimg.org/7q5c7t44l/KALEIDOSCOPE_Thumb_hover.png">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- AOHH -->

<div class ="card">
    <div class="no-hover"> 
        <img class="right ArtofHealthyHair" src="http://postimg.org/image/n7subiald/">

    </div>
    <div class="on-hover">
        <a href="Html/AOHH.html">
            <img class=" right ArtofHealthyHair" src="http://s21.postimg.org/u56jpto4n/Artof_Healthy_Hair_Hover.png">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>  

<!-- Nexxus  -->
<div class ="card mt100">
    <div class="no-hover mt100"> 
        <img class=" left Nexxus" src="http://s16.postimg.org/e05nrx9ut/Nexxus.png">

    </div>
    <div class="on-hover mt100">
        <a href="Nexxus.html">
            <img class="left Nexxus" src="http://s21.postimg.org/g00qo0f3b/Nexxus_Hover.png">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>  


<!-- Covergirl -->
<div class ="card">
    <div class="no-hover"> 
        <img class="whiteOverlay right CoverGirl" src="http://s16.postimg.org/lh9ta0t2d/Cover_Girl.png">

    </div>
    <div class="on-hover">
        <a href="Html/CoverGirlByKendallG.html">
            <img class="whiteOverlay right CoverGirl" src="http://s21.postimg.org/6n05jwbc7/Cover_Girl_Hover.png">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>  

<!-- PRTR -->

<div class ="card">
    <div class="no-hover"> 
        <img class="whiteOverlay left PRTR" src="http://s16.postimg.org/ee6zrityd/PRTR.png">
    </div>
    <div class="on-hover">
        <a href="Html/RTR.html">
            <img class="whiteOverlay left PRTR" src="http://s21.postimg.org/edbj2s31j/RTR_Hover.png">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Pantene -->
<div class ="card">
    <div class="no-hover"> 
        <img class="whiteOverlay right Pantnene" src="http://s16.postimg.org/3xqvp6uxx/Pantnene.png">
    </div>
    <div class="on-hover">
        <a href="Html/Pantene.html">
            <img class="whiteOverlay right Pantnene" src="http://s16.postimg.org/wia0c5rmt/WIOL_Hover.png">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    border: black 10px solid;
    font-family: 'brandon_grotesque_regularRg', Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: normal;
}


a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

#topMenu{
    right: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    z-index: 24;
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: "kern";
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "kern";
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "kern=1";

}

.MenuBar{
    text-align: center;
    width: 65%;
    margin:17 auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: "kern";
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "kern";
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "kern=1";


}
.consocials{
    bottom: 40;
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-right: 70px;
    width: 80%;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.consocials:hover{
    border-bottom:solid black 2px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;   
}

.socials{
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.socials:hover{
    border-bottom:solid black 2px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;

}

.socials:active{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.center{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.left{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 70px;
}

.right{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 70px;
}
.rightNoMargin{
    float: right;   
}

.bottom{
    bottom: 30px;
}

.hide{
    display: none;
}

.m0a{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.m10a{
    margin: 10 auto;
}
.h100{
    height: 100%;
}

.w100{
    width: 100%;
}
.w85{
    width: 85%;
}

.w50{
    width: 50%;
}
.w49{
    width: 49%;
}

.w40{
    width: 40%;
}
.mb200{
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.mb100{
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.pb30{
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.FloatL{
    float: left; 
}

.FloatR{
    float: right; 
}

.tAc{
    text-align: center;
}

.iLb{
    display: inline-block;
}

.m3{
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.h90{
    height: 90%;
}
.h850p{
    height: 850px;
}


.vA{
    vertical-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.h75{
    height: 60%
}

.pl20p{
    padding-left: 19%;
}

.pR100px{
    padding-right: 75px;
}

.w450{
    width: 450px;
}

.absolute{
    position: absolute;
}
.relative{
    position: relative;
}

.mnh100{
    min-height: 100px;

}

.mt100px{
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.mt200px{
    margin-top: 200px;
}
.h700{
    height: 700px;
}

.h800{
    height: 800px;
}

.w89{
    width: 89%;
}

.mT20{
    margin-top: 20%;
}

.mt50p{
    margin-top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your border isn't wrapping the image elements is because the image elements are floated and the container hasn't been cleared.

Anytime you float an image or any other object you take it out of the **[normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#normal-flow)**. This means that the parent container doesn't even know it exists.

There are several ways to address this issue – known as **[clearfix methods](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/)**. In this case I've used the `overflow` property. Add `overflow: auto` to the container `div`s.

```
.no-hover {overflow: auto;}
.on-hover {overflow: auto;}
```

I tested this code and it solves the problem.

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/hgaLsaz6/4/)

Just keep in mind that when using the `overflow` property you can have different values (`auto`, `hidden`, `scroll`) each of which will have a different effect when content overflows the container. To understand what each value does you can refer to this article: [MDN - CSS Overflow Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: This answer was downvoted after it was accepted by the OP and during an extended discussion with third-party users over various edits I made to the question. (The OP was not involved in the discussion.) Considering that these downvotes occurred at the same time I received criticism for helping the OP edit the question, I don't believe these downvotes relate to the quality of my answer. It seems that a moderator has deleted all the comments.

Comment: and I'm here to make it right :-)